# Add a row bellow a row which is already added by the same function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple table where i want to make a function to add rows at the end of the table using excel vba.

The problem is I don't know how every time when I add the new row to be at the end of the table.

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far? [It’s hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Suggestion: Work with finding the currently last used row in your macro. There are plenty of examples around on here and the internet that will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table's [ListRows.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listrows-add-method-excel) method.

```
With Worksheets("sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    .ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End With
```